# View previous checkins in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

We recently switched from VS2010 to VS2012, and I can't seem to find the list of TFS check-ins. For instance, I would like to see a list of all the checkins done by a specific user. Any ideas as to where can I find that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up source control explorer, click the following button in the toolbar [image: Find Changesets Button]  the following window will popup.

[image: find changesets dialog]

Comment: Perfect! Thought I would be able to find it under the "Pending Changes" menu, and didn't think to look in the SC Explorer. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option I just discovered: Right click a node in the file hierarchy, and choose **Find** ==>  **Find Changesets**:

[image: Right click a node in the file hierarchy, and choose File --> Find Changesets]

This will give you the same window as in the accepted answer.